# What should be the diffusion settings for a molten metal in mantaflow?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm still new to the blender community and to blender itself, and I've been trying to figure out what the diffusion settings of liquid molten metal would be like. I was going to make a liquid gold simulation like the one in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5pTehnItrA

Comment: What do you mean by diffusion settings? Are you talking about PBR values?

Comment: I meant the diffusion settings under the physics properties tab, where we can edit the base, exponent and surface tension. The one in this screenshot:
[link](https://pasteboard.co/JozB9zq.png)